# directcast in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, directcast

i have 1 a.master page and 1 b.aspx with its b.aspx.vb page. I have the following property in the a.master.vb

```
Public Property Page_Title() As String
    Get
        Return title_div.InnerHtml
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        title_div.InnerHtml = value
    End Set
End Property
```

in the b.aspx.vb page i have

```
DirectCast(Page.Master, a_am).Page_Title = "/images/img1.png"
```

but when i open the a.aspx page, it shows the text /images/img1.png and not the image. how do i make it show that image i want

Answer (score 2):

You've told it to make the `InnerHtml` just the string "/images/img1.png" - how did you expect that to be automatically translated into an image tag? Try this:

```
DirectCast(Page.Master, a_am).Page_Title = "<img src='/images/img1.png' />"
```

For the sake of accessibility etc you should really have some "alt" text etc, mind you...

Answer (score 0):

You are adding html to the page, so you need to put valid html into the string:

```
DirectCast(Page.Master, a_am).Page_Title = "<img src='/images/img1.png' />"
```